# Marketo Rest API - Get Folder Token Type: Local, Inherited or Overridden

Tags: api, rest, marketo

I've build a simple application to be able to create folder tokens using the Marketo REST API:

[Marketo REST APIs: Get Tokens by Folder Id](http://developers.marketo.com/documentation/asset-api/get-tokens-by-folder-id/)

From the Marketo Portal, I can see that inside a folder, tokens are grouped by type :

- Local: tokens created inside the folder
- Inherited: tokens that have been created in a parent folder.
- Overridden: tokens that have been created in a parent folder but that the value has been overridden in the folder.

I would like to be able to group tokens in my application doing the same.
From Marketo documentation, I can't see any token type inside the Json result.

The only workaround I've found is to query both the folder and it parent folder so that I will be able to compare tokens and determine their types:

- If the token doesn't exist in the parent folder, this is a local token.
- If the token exists in the parent folder and has the same value, this is an inherited token.
- If the token exists in the parent folder and has a different value, this is an overridden token.

I would like to know if there is any way to get the token type from the Json response without to query both folder and parent folder ?

Thanks in advance ^^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The token state can't be read from the response, so your best bet would be to to infer it in the manner you described.